# Value of previous variable becomes value of current variable

Tags: java

I got a problem with my code. As I try to compare two variables with different values by calling isEqual() method. But it gave me a result of true. Can someone spot the problem?
My FloatingPoint Class

```
import io.*;

//Class FloatingPoint

public class FloatingPoint
{

    //Constant
    public static final double MINPRECISION = 0.00000001;

    //Variable
    private static double precision;

    //Default constructor
    public FloatingPoint()
    {
        precision = MINPRECISION;
    }

    //Unsure if need a alternatve
    //Alternative constructor
    public FloatingPoint(double value)
    {
        if( (value < 0.0) || (value > 1.0) )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid reliability!");
        }
        setPrecision(value);
    }

    //Copy Constructor
    public FloatingPoint(FloatingPoint num)
    {
        precision = num.getPrecision();
    }

    //getPrecision
    public double getPrecision()
    {
        return precision;
    }

    //isEqual
    public boolean isEqual(FloatingPoint num)
    {
        return (Math.abs(precision - num.getPrecision()) < MINPRECISION);
    }

    //setPrecision
    public static void setPrecision(double value)
    {
        precision = value;
    }
}
```

And this is my Main Class

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestFloatingPoint
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        FloatingPoint f1, f2;
        f1= new FloatingPoint(0.2);
        System.out.print(f1.toString());

        f2=new FloatingPoint(1.0);
        System.out.print(f2.toString());
        System.out.print(f1.toString());

        System.out.print(f1.isEqual(f2));
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are storing the value in `precision` and don't have a `value` field in your class... it's not at all clear what your intention is.

Comment: `private static double precision` - I suggest you read up on static variables.

Comment: Hi there, but if I have to use static for the variable precision, is there any other way to solve?

Answer (score 1):

> As I try to compare two variables with different values by calling isEqual() method.

You don't have variables with different values, because you only have *one* value - a static variable:

```
private static double precision;
```

(Change the declaration of `setPrecision` to not be static too.)

Declaring that as `static` means it's associated with the type rather than with any instance of your type. Your class doesn't declare any *instance* fields, and therefore doesn't have any state (other than object identity).

The simple fix is to make it an instance field:

```
private double precision;
```

But you should read up more on what `static` means so you can decide when to use it and when not to use it in the future. See the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Hi Jon, but if I have to use static my variable precision and  public static void setPrecision(double value), is there any other way to solve?

Comment: @Auric: Yes, you need to make that *method* non-static too. Think about it - if you call `FloatingPoint.setPrecision(5.0)` which object do you want that to affect?

Comment: Hi Jon, do you mean remove the word static?

Comment: But if I want to keep the word static for that method, should I add  another private variable to compare ?

Comment: @Auric: Then you should seriously think about what you're actually trying to achieve. Why do you want one piece of type-wide mutable state, and one piece of per-instance mutable state?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the static. Static means that **all the objects** of type `FloatingPoint` will share the same value. **So if you change one, all of them will change.**

```
    //Variable
    private double precision;


//setPrecision
    public void setPrecision(double value)
    {
        precision = value;
    }
```

Also note that, you can call a `static` field from a `none static` method (Because `static` is `shared` for all objects of the same class), but you can't use a `none static` field in a `static` method (**because there is no object to get the value from**). I think if you get this concept, you can solve your problem easily.

```
FloatingPoint f1, f2;
f1= new FloatingPoint(0.2);
// Here f1 has precision = 0.2
System.out.print(f1.toString());

f2=new FloatingPoint(1.0);
// Here f1 and f2 have precision = 1.0
```

Comment: hi there, yes, actually I knew if I remove static , everything will be correct, but I have to use static for my setPrecision and my variable precision

Comment: check the edited answer, if you change precision for `f2`, it will change for `f1` also, because it is `static`. You need to remove static from `precision variable` and from `setPrecision` also.

Comment: I try to avoid "all the objects" sharing a value as a concept - because there don't have to be *any* objects. I just model it as "the variable is associated with the type rather than any one instance of the type".

Comment: You're absolutely correct Jon, but i think it is much easier for newcomers to understand it this way. There is one copy of each static field which everyone can access (So they share it).

Comment: @user3185569: Only in the same way that all strings share that field as well. I think it's much better to avoid giving a misleading impression (that it's shared between a pool of objects than that it's completely independent of *any* of the objects) - *particularly* for newcomers, as once they've got that misleading understanding, it's harder to fix.